# PHP Return true in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, methods, foreach, return

I want to check if the user is using the default settings. In the example below, I'm trying to check if all "foreached" items return `true`. If a single foreached item doesn't return `true`, return `false` on the whole function.

```
private function is_using_default_settings() {
    // returns a huge array with settings
    $merged_preset = $this->options_merged();

    foreach($merged_preset as $preset) {
        if($preset[5] == 1) {
            $section = 'general';
        } elseif($preset[5] == 2) {
            $section = 'advanced';
        } elseif($preset[5] == 3) {
            $section = 'technical';
        }

        $option = get_option($section);

        if($preset[3] == $option[$preset[0]] && !is_null($preset[1])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I've been brainstorming for the past few days to get this sorted on my own, but sadly cannot get it to work. What is the best approach to this?

Comment: You actually wrote it yourself: *If a single foreached item doesn't return true, return false* - Test for `false` in your foreach (eg. switch your logic around) and return false if any item doesn't match. If all match, return true at the end of the function.

Comment: you need to look at this the other way. `return false` if one doesn't match and only `return true` when the loop finished. that way, if _any_ section is false, it will return false.

Comment: What happens when `$preset[5]` isn't 1, 2 or 3? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can check when is false and block the full foreach then return value, if all is true return value true

try this:

```
private function is_using_default_settings() {
    $returnValue = true;
    $merged_preset = $this->options_merged();

    foreach($merged_preset as $preset) {
        if($preset[5] == 1) {
            $section = 'general';
        } elseif($preset[5] == 2) {
            $section = 'advanced';
        } elseif($preset[5] == 3) {
            $section = 'technical';
        }

        $option = get_option($section);

        if($preset[3] != $option[$preset[0]] || is_null($preset[1])) {
            $returnValue = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return false when any check fails in the foreach, otherwise return true.

```
function check()
{
  foreach($arr as $v)
  {
     //check fails
     if(fail of the check) 
         return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```